# How to integrate $\sqrt x \cdot e^{x^{3/2}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How do you integrate $\sqrt x \cdot e^{x^{3/2}}$?

Can I get a step by step process? You can leave out basic integration rules. I don't know how they get $\frac 23 e^{x^{3/2}} + c$.

Where does the $\frac 23$ come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: $d x^{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{x} dx$

Comment: Still can't figure out why its 2/3. Please explain more?

Comment: what happens if you multiply by $\frac{2}{3}$?

Comment: Sqr of x is x^0.5? I'm lost.

Comment: $\sqrt{x} dx = \frac{2}{3}d(x^{\frac{3}{2}}$)

Comment: Yep I got that my final answer is ; 2/3*x^1.5 * e^x^1.5 + c.  What happened to the x^1.5 after the 2/3?

Comment: you substitute $x^{\frac{3}{2}} = u$ and got the table integral $\int e^u du = e^u +c$ and plugged $u(x)$ back. plus your constant

Answer (score 2):

Hint: substitute $\displaystyle u = e^{x^\frac{3}{2}}$. Don't neglect to express the $\displaystyle dx$ in terms of $du$.

Comment: that's a whole extra step, maybe two. An overkill for such a simple problem.

Comment: @Alex Perhaps. But for someone who can't immediately "see it" - I'm not talking about myself, but the OP, this should be clearer. I see that you have to explain yourself further to the OP in comments after your answer. This allows one to reduce the problem to $\int \frac{2}{3}du$. But just subbing for the exponent is fine as well, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Put $z=x^{\frac32}$ to get $dz=\frac32 \sqrt x dx$

Hence $\int  \sqrt x e^{x^{\frac32}}dx=\frac23\int e^z dz=\frac23 e^z +c=\frac23 e^{x^{\frac32}} +c$

Comment: You are welcome..it is good that my answer helped you..

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be overseeing that

$$(x^m)'=mx^{m-1}\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb R$$

and thus

$$(x^{3/2})'=\frac32x^{3/2-1}=\frac32x^{1/2}=\frac32\sqrt x$$

Now, for any differentiable function $\;f(x)\;$ , applying the chain rule we have that

$$\left(e^{f(x)}\right)'=f'(x)e^{f(x)}\implies \int f'(x)\,e^{f(x)}dx=e^{f(x)}+C\text{ (=constant)}$$

and thus, from all this, we have

$$\int\sqrt x\,e^{x^{3/2}}dx =\frac23\int\overbrace{\left(\frac32\sqrt x\right)}^{(x^{3/2})'}e^{x^{3/2}}dx=\frac23e^{x^{3/2}}+C$$